# using XML Schema definition for a List in List in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am serializing a class to xml `using System.Xml.Serialization`.

```
    [XmlArray("Contentlist")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Filter")]
    public List<List<String>> ContentList { get; set; }
```

results:

```
   <Contentlist>
     <Filter>
       <string>...</string>
     </Filter>
   </Contentlist>
```

How could i use XML Schema definition to replace "string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining `ContentList` as `List<List<string>>` you could create a little helper class:

```
public class YourSerializedClass
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Filter")]
    public List<Filter> ContentList { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    [XmlElement("FilterItem")]
    public List<string> FilterItems { get; set; }
}
```

That should create a xml structure like you have described.

Comment: You can even omit the `XmlArrayItemAttribute` at property `ContentList` if the helper class is called "Filter"